# Error Messages not showing inside Alert Dialog Box

Tags: java, android-studio, android-alertdialog, email-validation, reset-password

I would like to show an error message within an alert dialog box for password reset, however no error message shows inside the dialog pop up.

[Alert Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykh67.jpg)

When clicking "Reset" the dialog box will close. However, entering in a valid email does show the toast message "Reset Email Sent"

The validations are 1) leaving the email address empty , 2)not giving a proper email

Login.java

```
//onclick for forgot password
    forgotPText = findViewById(R.id.forgotPassText);
    forgotPText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //start alert dialog
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reset_popup,null);
            reset_alert.setTitle("Forgot Password ?")
                    .setMessage("Enter Email For Password Reset Link.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Reset", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //validate the email address is not empty or not valid email
                            EditText email = view.findViewById(R.id.reset_popup_Email);
                            String emailChar = email.getText().toString();
                            if (email.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                                email.setError("Required Field!");
                                return;
                            }
                            if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailChar).matches()){
                                email.setError("Please provide valid email!");
                                email.requestFocus();
                                return;
                            }
                            //send reset link
                            firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email.getText().toString())
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    //FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    //updateUI(user);
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this
                                            , "Reset Email Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
                    .setView(view)
                    .create().show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
forgotPText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //start alert dialog
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                AlertDialog.Builder reset_alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reset_popup,null);
                reset_alert.setView(view);

                EditText email = view.findViewById(R.id.email);
                TextView tv_cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cancel);
                TextView tv_submit = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_submit);

                tv_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() { alertDialog.dismiss(); }}, 200);
                    }
                });

                email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (!hasFocus) {
                            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        }
                    }
                });

                tv_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);


                        String emailChar = email.getText().toString();


                        if (email.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                            email.setError("Required Field!");
                             return;
                        }

                         if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailChar).matches()){
                            email.setError("Please provide valid email!");
                            email.requestFocus();
                             return;
                         }
                        //send reset link
                        firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email.getText().toString())
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        //FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                        //updateUI(user);
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this
                                                , "Reset Email Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                alertDialog = reset_alert.create();
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });


////////   reset_popup.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reset_alert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/des"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Enter Email For Password Reset Link."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reset_alert" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/des" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_submit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="353dp"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What would alertDialog be initialized as?

Comment: Would it be : final AlertDialog alertDialog = reset_alert.create();

Comment: This is the answer , got it working after initializing alertDialog to reset_alert.create().  Now I know how to have error messages in alert dialogs in the future. Thank you!